# SwiftUI FocusState onChange

Tags: swiftui

In my view I have FocusState variable `@FocusState var detailFocus: FlightField?`. I have an onChange modifier listening to the change of focus of the `detailFocus`.

```
.onChange(of: detailFocus) { isFocused in
            
            if isFocused == .distance {
                // Code Runs when detailFocus = .distance
            }
```

As is, the code runs when the field gains focus, is there a way to trigger `.onChange` when the focus was `.distance` and changed to something else (not nil)? The fields are dynamically created (the surrounding fields are always different).

Comment: So you want `.onChange(of: detailFocus) { old, new in if old == .distance && new != nil { ... } }`? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, however isn’t this one (oldValue, newValue) available from iOS 17 onwards?

Comment: Correct. What versions are you supporting?

Comment: If you are pre iOS 17 then you just need to use a captured parameter: `.onChange(of: detailFocus) { [oldVal = detailFocus] newVal in`

Comment: I go back to iOS16. The [oldVal] newVal works, thanks for this:)